# Using Readium in WebApp

Tags: javascript, c#, readiumjs

I am trying to build an web application to read epubs using readium js but the problem is i can not find an appropriate example.
If anyone knows an example in javascript or C# to achieve the same please help me out.

Comment: https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [readium-js-viewer](https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer)?

Comment: Recently they have changed the project. Now, I am confused between the names. There is a Chrome-app and there is JS viewer. Which one is this?

Comment: I do not follow this project recently. But the link I posted is still there?